# Difference between serving single resource to many vs. many resources to many?

Tags: performance, webserver

What's the performance difference between a web server serving the same file to 10 people vs. 10 different files to 10 different people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very little.

However if it was serving 1 file to 100,000 people vs. 100,000 files to 100,000 people then you might see a difference, as the single file can be cached in memory whereas the large number may not be able to be cached, so you'd see a lot of disk IO.

This assumes you're talking about static files (e.g. images).
If you're talking about scripts then what the script actually does will be the main factor.

Comment: Yes, in this case I'm thinking about static files

Comment: +1. And if any of those 100,000 people share a caching proxy, then the question is different again...

Comment: Specifically, we are loading a large random image on each page reuqest. Would there be any performance advantage if every visitor is seeing the same image at the same time?

Comment: Probably not enough to be worth changing your code but it really depends on your exact circumstances